# Returning AJAX responseText as string

Tags: ajax, responsetext

In my code I attempt to use AJAX to fetch the content of a template file and return it as a string, which I alert. This results in `undefined`, however if instead of `return xmlhttp.responseText` I do `alert(xmlhttp.responseText)` I get the result I'm after.

Can I return the AJAX content as a string outside the function??

```js
alert(getFile());

function getFile() {

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function stateChanged() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
      return xmlhttp.responseText;
  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","/template.html", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest is async. You should use callback like below

```
getFile(alert);

function getFile(callback) {

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function stateChanged() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
      callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","/template.html", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Cool, so rather than alerting the result, how would I return it as a string I can use elsewhere? (also, if I want to pass `"/template.html"` to the function as an argument, how would I do that?

Comment: You can only use result in callback. The signature is `getFile(fileName, callback)` like Node.js' function `fs.readFile(file, callback)`

Comment: Ok, so I can't pull the value out of the function at all?

Answer (score 1):

No: to do what you want, you need to accept a callback in your `getFile` function and invoke it:

```
function getFile(callback) {

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function stateChanged() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
      callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","/template.html", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send();
}

getFile(alert);
```